# Regex match for XML Query Paths?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following paths:

```
/A      
/A/B        
/A/B/C      
/A/D        
/A/D/E      
/A/D/E/F        
/A/D/E/F/H      
/A/D/E/G        
/A/D/E/G/I      
/A/D/E/F/J      
/A/D/E/G/D
```

I want to apply a regular expression to get the matched paths.

I have tried the following regex `^/A/(.*)/D$` and it gives only the last path which is `/A/D/E/G/D`. What i want is a regex to get the fourth path and the last path.

The expected output is:

```
/A/D    
/A/D/E/G/D
```

Comment: in `/A/D/E/G/D`, you want `G` and `D`

Comment: Split with `/` and get the elements you need.

Comment: It seems that you got my question wrong. The output i want are not the elements of the path. I want the whole path. The expected output i am looking for is /A/D  and  /A/D/E/G/D

Comment: I want the fourth path and the last path from the list of paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a superfluous slash in your pattern!

Try this patern, it should work:

```
^\/A(.*)\/D$
```

Demo: [view demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR0bA6/1)

**Edit:**
Or if you want want to get all parts, just set the group this way:

```
^(\/A.*\/D)$
```

Demo: [view 2nd demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW4qC6/1)

Comment: You do not have to escape the forward slashes in C# regex patterns.